# CSS border-radius doesn´t apply to border arround the div

Tags: css

I have a problem with my CSS. I add the border-radius poperty to a div element.
The background-color shows rounded corners, so this works.
But the border around the div keeps his sharp corners.

My css looks like this:

```
padding-top:1px;
padding-left:2px;
background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#B5B5B5,GradientType=1);
height: 245px;
padding-right: 30px !important;
border: 1px solid silver;
border-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: Can you add the CSS selectors as well as your HTML?

Comment: its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/L28xgcLp/

Comment: natural it should work. give us more information like wavemaster says.

Comment: When i run the code border radius is working.for more border radius increase the pixel  as border-radius:25px;

Comment: The background-color rounds off at the corners, this workes. But ony the border itself keeps its corners.
with a higher border radius it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/xmHfNvD.png

Comment: @YannickSchneider Which browser do you use for testing this?

Comment: Firefox 40.0.2 and Chrome 44.0.2403.155
Both the latest Version

Comment: Pelase *reproduce* the error in a demo (perhaps on JSFiddle.net ) or a Stack Snippet. Offhand this looks like an wrapper or `outline` issue,

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me in Chrome 44/Win 7

```css
div {
    padding-top:1px;
    padding-left:2px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#B5B5B5, GradientType=1);
    height: 245px;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 5px
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually correct. See snippet below.

The only reasons the radius wouldn't show are:

- Your browser does not support it.

*(In this case the code below will also not appear to work when you view it).*

- You are **overwriting** the `border-radius` elsewhere in your code.

```css
.myDiv{
  padding-top:1px;
  padding-left:2px;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#B5B5B5,GradientType=1);
  height: 245px;
  padding-right: 30px !important;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">HELLO</div>
```

**TESTING**

To determine if another style is overwriting your border-radius:

**SET**

```
border-radius: 5px !important;
```

If your borders are now rounded then the style is being overwritten elsewhere.

**NOTE:** *I do not recommend this as the solution, only as a means to determine the problem.*

Comment: I checked it with the developer tools of firefox and chrome. At both I couldn´t see any css which overwrite my border-radius.
Also I used border-radius at some other places and it worked fine there.

Comment: @see my notes above to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```css
.curve{
padding-top:1px;
padding-left:2px;
background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #B5B5B5 100%, #eeeeee 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#B5B5B5,GradientType=1);
height: 245px;
padding-right: 30px !important;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
/* multiple browser support */
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="curve">Div Content</div>
```